# Loading external esmodule on Create React App (w/o ejection)

Tags: webpack, module, create-react-app, micro-frontend

I have build an esmodule app and need to load it through an import on a host app (this is a micro-frontend app). I understand that a non-ejected project created with CRA is unable to manipulate its webpack configurations, and that in order for webpack to load it it needs to be included within the source folder. Is there a way to dynamically load an external component from a remote location on a CRA project w/o the need to eject it?